# Is using RPC with Masstransit best practice if you are trying to get a response from a queue

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I thought using RPC is bad practice but all the resources I am finding point to using RPC in order to get a response from a queue after publishing a request. Are there any other ways of doing it? Is it the best practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

MassTransit has built-in support for producing [requests](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/requests.html) (which can be published, or sent directly to a specific endpoint). The request client can be created manually or added to a dependency injection container, and one or more response types can be handled.

MassTransit uses the bus endpoint to receive responses by default.

To register the request client in the container, the `AddRequestClient` method is used as shown below.

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    // configure transport/host/etc.

    x.AddRequestClient<CheckOrderStatus>();
});
```

RPC is a common pattern, and producing requests when a response is required, it a regularly used approach. Another option is combining a command with an event, and observing the event separate from the request producer. However, if a linear programmatic flow is required, using RPC via the request client is an easy solution.